# Get a var from a config file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using a package (aws) and I wish to get a var from it's config file.

The config file is located in:

```
config>packages>aws>aws-sdk-php-laravel>config
```

I've tried:

Config::get('packages.aws.aws-sdk-php-laravel.config.key')

But no luck, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Config is easily accessed and Laravel has support for packages. The structure for calling it would be.

```
Config::get('package::file.option');
```

I've just taken a look at the package you are using, and they've set up a nice handy namespace for access. Since the package only has one config file, you can also omit that, like so:

```
Config::get('aws::key');
```

For more information regarding third party package configuration, here's the Laravel documentation on the subject http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-configuration.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the package notation for config files:

```
Config::get('aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel::key');
```

And you may also have to add the namespace to Laravel:

```
Config::addNamespace('aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel', __DIR__.'/path/to/config');
```